# how to still have control with sleep?

Tags: command-line, command

I computed a clock on a file exerciceIV_2.C with the `gedit` command of unix,
And, by a night of september, I decided to use `sleep 1000` in order to stop the clock.

I wasn't able to use my device for 1000 seconds!
hopefully I called a friend who told me to use CTRL+C.
How should we do in order to still stop the clock while having control?

Comment: This is not about Unix or Linux, it's a (beginner's!) programming question

Comment: @wurtel Yes, I know, If you had read the comments, you would know that I would have deleted it!
and beginner or not it's still a question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while syntax is

```
while ( cond ) expr ;
```

you cannot add a ! before (

On a side note, this question would have better fit stackoverflow.

Comment: ow! thanks! sorry, I was using unix so I thought... whatever! I'm deleting it right after I make it working.